# If T is in the set of complex polynomials, prove that the matrix of T w.r.t. the standard basis of T is upper triangular

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we have that $p \in \mathbb{P}_m(\mathbb{C})$ is the set of all polynomials with complex coefficients with degree less than or equal to m.

And that $T$ is the differentiation operator:

$Tp=p'$

Now, let $(1,x,x^2, ...,x^m)$ be a standard basis.

Prove that the matrix w.r.t. the standard basis is upper triangular.

My solution:

If we can show that $Tv_k \in span(v_1,...,v_k)$, for each $k=1,...,m$, and $v_k \in (1,x,x^2, ...,x^m)$, then by a proposition this is saying that T is upper triangular.

Since T is the differentiation operator, every transformation of $v_k$ will result in a polynomial with degree $k-2$, hence since the span of $(v_1,...,v_k)$ has degree at most $k-1$, the resulting transformation has got to be in the span and hence $T$ has an upper triangular matrix.

Would this proof work? And does the fact that the coefficients are in the complex space change anything if I were instead to work with the reals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(x^k)=kx^{k-1}$, thus the matrix $A=(a_{i,j})$ of $T$ has
$$
a_{k,k+1}=k
$$
and $0$ in the other places. Just look at it and you see it's upper triangular.